# Multi window plugin in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, multi-window

We are developing a large scale application in angular. It has separated multiple modules and more than 100 pages per module. It is a garment ERP. A lot of business is here. Many times the client wants to see multiple pages at a time and they want to feature minimize and maximize. That is their requirements is like desktop pages. So how can we create multi-window in angular?

We have found a jquery plugin http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/ but our requirements are angular, Have any angular multi window like as jquery.
Thanks, everybody.

```
> At first please see the jquery link http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/.
> I have to make this window by using the angular directive.
```

Comment: Those are not real browser windows, are they?

Comment: Hi, @Shomz, Thanks your reply. Yes, it will be custom window, do you have any idea to you?

Comment: Well, you can create a popup-type window using templating system ans CSS, shouldn't be too hard, really. And the good thing is that you won't have to worry about different apps (like you would have to in case you wanted something to work across multiple browser windows/tabs).

Comment: @Shomz, your idea is very good. but i am seeking a sample with minimum feature then i will add more feature.

Comment: @Shohel Have you solved it ? If so, how ? ?

Answer (score 1):

This one displays multiple windows which can be dragged around and maximized. But it doesn't appear to support minimizing (temporarily collapsing) windows.

https://github.com/sinmsinm/ng-window-manager

You could also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888171/how-to-implement-gmail-compose-window-concept-in-single-page-applications).

Comment: (We ended up hacking our own using Bootstrap popups. When the user minimised windows, we stacked them in the bottom-right using `float: left` and `transform: rotate(180)` twice!