# Angular bootstrap modal open onload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ modal.

Now i want to open Modal whenever page loads

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {                
                 open('lg');         
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ has a  directive and the $modal service and both of those can be used to open modal windows.

you then need to use:

```
$modal.dialog({}).open('modalContent.html');
```

there is a similar question in here: [Invoking modal window in AngularJS Bootstrap UI using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265844/invoking-modal-window-in-angularjs-bootstrap-ui-using-javascript)

Comment: Forgot to add that i need to open template, not url.

Comment: @user2614879 Then pass an object with the options, instead of a url.

Comment: well this will open a template name modalCotnen.html you can added a variable and in the variable just enter the tempalte if it's not at static file

Comment: it's accualy MVC's View. Not html file, but templateURL.

Comment: you need to add $dialog to the controller also make sure you installed angular-ui

Comment: FYI `$dialog` doesn't exist anymore. You can see in this [changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/e420204fa21e43939e3dfa75c28e4a310a56e931/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) `$dialog service was refactored into $modal`.

Answer (score 1):

Module API has a `run` method. In your code for you app you add code to open the dialog in the run callback

```
angular.module('myAppModule').run(function($modal) {
  $modal.open(options);   //the option data. See documentation.
});
```

Comment: Not working...

angular.module('transport').run(function($modal) {
  $modal.open({templateUrl: 'deleteCheked.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size : size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;}});   //the option data. See documentation.
});

Comment: That modal does not exsits.

Comment: error is gone (was mismatch of myAppModule name). Now problem is that nothing happens when angular.module is runned (event alert does not shoot)