# Angular-UI Bootstrap Modal trigger on page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Whilst I have looked at the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780767/angular-bootstrap-modal-open-onload), I'm still unable to trigger my `openModal()` function on page load.

Within my controller, I have the code (below question), which does allow `openModal()` to trigger fine either from an ng-click directive or when entering the following in the Chrome console:

`angular.element($0).scope().openModal()`

My problem is when I'm trying to conditionally open the modal upon page load. My current code is:

```
$scope.openModal = function (size) {

    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'pageBuilder',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.chosenDeploymentSchedule;
            }
        }
    });
};

angular.element(document).ready(function () {

//  $scope.openModal();
    console.log('Hello World');
});
```

I do get my `Hello World` printing, but when I try uncommenting the `$scope.openModal();`, I get an infinite loop of `undefined` + `Hello World` printing out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this solution is too late for this question but may be useful for someone.

1. Create your normal bootstrap modal

   ```
   $scope.myDialog = function () {
       $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'templatefolder/modal.html',
          backdrop: 'static',
          windowClass: 'modal',
          size: 'lg',
          controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
               $scope.cancel = function () {
                  $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
               };
             }
       });
   };
   ```
2. Call the modal in your html page like so `<span ng-init="myDialog()"></span>`

That's it. This works for me and I hope it will work for someone too.

Comment: ng-init did it!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$scope.openModal()` directly underneath where you define it in the controller. It'll open the modal right away.

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine for me. Can you produce a plunkr to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst still unable to call it directly from within the same controller, my solution was to add another method which gets called from an `ng-init` in the view:

```
$scope.launchModalConditionally = function(){
    if(!$scope.gotCredentials){
        $scope.openModal();
    }
};
```