# Angular js with Bootstrap modal - Re clicking event doesn't trigger properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular js with bootstrap modal
I have this Anchor link

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteFriendModal" ><span class="frndInvt"></span>Invite Friends</a></li>
```

When i click on this

i am opening this modal box code

```
  <div id="inviteFriendModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" ng-controller="inviteFriendsCtrl">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="showSuccessAlert">
                    <strong>{{successTextAlert}}</strong> 
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-fail" ng-show="showfailAlert">
                <strong>{{failTextAlert}}</strong> 
            </div>
        <div class="forCancelButton text-right"><button data-dismiss="modal"></button></div>
          <div class="modalMsg" ng-hide="InviteForm"><p>
            <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
                <div class="formRow"><tags-input ng-model="emails" allowed-tags-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$" placeholder="Add an Email" add-on-space="true"  > </tags-input></div>
                <div class="formRow"><textarea rows="5" cols="52" ng-model="message">Hello my custom message </textarea></div>
            </p>
          <div class="actionsBtns">
            <button class="doneModal" ngClick="Submit" >Yes</button>
            <button class="cancelModal" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          </div></form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and this is my Controller

```
app.controller('inviteFriendsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({ 
      url: "invitefriends",
      data: {emails:$scope.emails,message:$scope.message},
      method: 'POST',
    }).success(function(data){
      $scope.InviteForm= true;
      $scope.successTextAlert = data;
      $scope.showSuccessAlert = true;


    }).error(function(err){ 
      $scope.InviteForm= true;
      $scope.failTextAlert = "There is some problem. Please try again";
      $scope.showfailAlert = true;        
    })

  };  
});
```

Which is working fine .

I got success message or fail message.

Now Problem is that . When i re-click anchor tag. it is opening sucess message. not a form.

I want to open form again when i reclick anchor tag.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use code inside modal as template and then append this template div in modal on success message.That will solve your problem.

Comment: @Innovation: i didn't get you. Can you please explain me

Comment: Another solution can be you handle onClose event of modal via simple javascript.

Comment: How. Could you provide example for that

Comment: I mean use modal code as template and on link click load the respective template.After first call success message assigned on the modal and when you re click the link it will show that success message.

Comment: Can't be do this in same code. loading template is not good idea. in this case. because i am not using ny template engine

Comment: AngularJs already have templating engine  check thease url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113/scope-issue-in-angularjs-using-angularui-bootstrap-modal   & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265844/invoking-modal-window-in-angularjs-bootstrap-ui-using-javascript

Comment: Use Angular UI Bootstrap or similar: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the value of $scope.InviteForm, $scope.showSuccessAlert and $scope.showfailAlert to false when clicked on the link.

Add ng-click to your link

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteFriendModal" ng-click="showForm()"><span class="frndInvt"></span>Invite Friends</a>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.showForm = function(){
    $scope.InviteForm = false;
    $scope.showSuccessAlert = false;
    $scope.showfailAlert = false;
}
```

Comment: How to do this. Could you provide example